# AWS file upload more than 5mb - nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using this module to upload file to amazon

https://www.npmjs.com/package/streaming-s3, which is working fine if file is less or equal than 5 MB.

I tried to upload PDF file with size 6 MB. it shows upload successfully, but when i tried to open that file through aws.

**it shows Failed to load PDF document**

When i checked size on Aws it shows 5 MB.

I am using following code to upload on AWS

```
var options = {
        concurrentParts: 2,
        waitTime: 20000,
        retries: 2,
        maxPartSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024
    };
    //call stream function to upload the file to s3
    var uploader = new streamingS3(fileReadStream, config.aws.accessKey, config.aws.secretKey, awsHeader, options);
    //start uploading
    uploader.begin();// important if callback not provided.

    // handle these functions
    uploader.on('data', function (bytesRead) {
        console.log(bytesRead, ' bytes read.');
    });

    uploader.on('part', function (number) {
        console.log('Part ', number, ' uploaded.');
    });

    // All parts uploaded, but upload not yet acknowledged.
    uploader.on('uploaded', function (stats) {
        console.log('Upload stats: ', stats);
    });

    uploader.on('finished', function (response, stats) {
        console.log(response);
        logger.log('info', "UPLOAD ", response);
        cb(null, response);
    });

    uploader.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('Upload error: ', err);
        logger.log('error', "UPLOAD Error: ", err);
        cb(err);
    });
```

which is working fine for less than 5 MB files.

Any idea? Is there is any settings which i need to do on AWS ?

Thanks

Comment: what do you get in the console? why did you change the maxPartSize ?

Comment: Upload stats:  { downloadSpeed: 5242880000,
  uploadSpeed: 66365570,
  downloadTime: 1,
  uploadTime: 79,
  size: 5242880 }

There is no error

Comment: do you see the FINISHED message?

Answer (score 0):

This is desired feature for piping the content to S3 via the multipart file upload API, you can keep memory usage low even when operating on a stream that is GB in size. This stream avoids high memory usage by flushing the stream to S3 in 5 MB parts such that it should only ever store 5 MB of the stream data at a time.

The problem that we are facing here is that the next part is not adding up to the stream.

Refer this link for end to end details
https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-upload-stream

you can also track the upload progress, to debug the issue using

```
/* Handle progress. Example details object:
   { ETag: '"f9ef956c83756a80ad62f54ae5e7d34b"',
     PartNumber: 5,
     receivedSize: 29671068,
     uploadedSize: 29671068 }
*/
upload.on('part', function (details) {
  console.log(details);
});
```

Even on complete file upload done.

```
upload.on('uploaded', function (details) {
  console.log(details);
});
```

Comment: you want to me to use s3-upload-stream this module ?

Comment: try using it, I have used it in the past and it is very promising